# SQL - Use OR operator in parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, parameters, or-operator

I’m using Oracle 11g and I have a simple query (report) using parameters in my WHERE clause, but I’m not able to use the OR operation efficiently.

My WHERE clause is:

```
WHERE
1=1
AND
(
   TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(seg.START) BETWEEN 0 AND [DaysBeforClass]
   OR
   TRUNC(seg.END) - TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN 0 AND [DaysAfterClass]
)
```

Please, note that:

- `seg.START` and `seg.END` are Date Time type
- `[DaysBeforClass]` and `[DaysAfterClass]` are the parameter to the end user (textbox)

What I need is that the user uses both parameter simultaneously and individually.

Currently, this WHERE clause works well when:

- the user uses both parameters simultaneously
- the user uses only the DaysBeforClass parameter

Any ideas?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Are you passing `NULL` for user not entered anything ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for a condition like this:

```
WHERE
   ( [DaysBeforClass] IS NULL OR TRUNC(seg.START) BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) - [DaysBeforClass] AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) )
   AND
   ( [DaysAfterClass] IS NULL OR TRUNC(seg.END) BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) + [DaysAfterClass] )
```

I use `TRUNC(seg.START) BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) - [DaysBeforClass] AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)` instead of `TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(seg.START) BETWEEN 0 AND [DaysBeforClass]` because then Oracle can utilize a function-based index on `TRUNC(seg.START)`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `TRUNC( column_name )` then Oracle cannot use an index on that column (and would have to have a function-based index instead). Alternatively you could use:

```
WHERE (  :DaysBeforClass IS NULL
      OR (   seg.START >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - :DaysBeforClass
         AND seg.START <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1
         )
      )
AND   (  :DaysAfterClass IS NULL
      OR (   seg.END   >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
         AND seg.END   <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) + :DaysAfterClass + 1
         )
      )
```

Comment: I assume the question is more related to "How to handle it if `DaysBeforClass` and/or `DaysAfterClass` is NULL?"

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I was just updating that.